# Выделенный текст в поле

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать, чтобы текст в поле был выделен?

Только не с помощью `autofocus="autofocus"`, а через JS, как это реализовано в ВК, когда кликаешь на свой статус.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно это... именно выделить или focus? это разные вещи. определитесь уж

```
document.getElementById("target-input-or-textfield").select();
```